# Text-editing app

Tags: javascript

I've made lots of improvements on my text-editing app.  Please review it again.

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  if (!window.File) document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Sorry your <a href='http://whatbrowser.org/'>browser</a> isn't supported :(</h1>";

  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
    statusBar = document.getElementById("status-bar"),
    inputFile = document.getElementById("input-file"),
    appname = "Notepad",
    statusBarOn,
    isModified,
    filename;

  function skipSave() {
    if (!isModified || !textarea.value || confirm("You have unsaved changes that will be lost.")) {
      isModified = false;
      return true;
    }
  }

  function changeFilename(newFilename) {
    filename = newFilename;
    document.title = filename + " - " + appname;
  }

  function updateStatusBar() {
    var text = textarea.value;
    statusBar.value = "Words: " + (text.split(/\b\S+\b/g).length - 1) + "  Characters: " + text.replace(/\s/g, "").length + " / " + text.replace(/\n/g, "").length;
  }

  function newDoc(text, newFilename) {
    if (skipSave()) {
      textarea.value = text || "";
      changeFilename(newFilename || "untitled.txt");
      updateStatusBar();
    }
  }

  function openDoc() {
    var file = inputFile.files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
      newDoc(reader.result, file.name);
    });
  }

  function renameDoc() {
    var newFilename = prompt("Name this document:", filename);
    if (newFilename !== null) {
      if (newFilename === "")
        changeFilename("untitled.txt");
      else
        changeFilename(newFilename.lastIndexOf(".txt") == -1 ? newFilename + ".txt" : newFilename);
      return true;
    }
  }

  function saveDoc() {
    if (renameDoc()) {
      var blob = new Blob([textarea.value.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n")], {
        type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
      });
      saveAs(blob, filename);
      isModified = false;
    }
  }

  function showHideStatusBar(toState) {
    statusBarOn = toState;
    statusBar.hidden = !statusBarOn;
    textarea.style.height = statusBarOn ? "calc(100% - 21px)" : "";
  }

  textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
    isModified = true;
    updateStatusBar();
  });

  inputFile.addEventListener("change", openDoc);

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { // kbd shortcuts
    var keys = {
      66: function() { // B ; toggle
        showHideStatusBar(!statusBarOn);
      },
      79: function() { // O ; open
        if (skipSave()) inputFile.click();
      },
      82: newDoc, // R
      83: saveDoc, // S
      "noctrl9": function() { // tab
        var text = textarea.value,
          sStart = textarea.selectionStart;
        textarea.value = text.substring(0, sStart) + "\t" + text.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
        textarea.selectionEnd = sStart + 1;
      }
    },
      f = e.ctrlKey ? keys[e.keyCode] : keys["noctrl" + e.keyCode];
    if (f) {
      e.preventDefault();
      f();
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var appdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(appname));
    if (appdata && appdata.isModified) {
      newDoc(appdata.text, appdata.filename);
      isModified = true;
    } else {
      newDoc();
    }
    showHideStatusBar(!appdata || appdata.statusBarOn);
  });

  window.addEventListener("unload", function() { // store data
    var appdata = {
      "isModified": isModified,
      "text": textarea.value,
      "filename": filename,
      "statusBarOn": statusBarOn
    };
    localStorage.setItem(appname, JSON.stringify(appdata));
  });
}());
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or jsbin ? This looks so much better than the first attempt.

Comment: You can see the full app here - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92126558/Notepad/index.html

Comment: whole app in a zip - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92126558/Notepad.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your code

- "Use Strict" within a IFFE
- No warnings in JsHint, good indenting
- Correct casing and decent naming
- Nice size of methods

I can only comment on the lack of comments in your source, though I admit the code is pretty self-explanatory.